# Could not find or load main class in Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4

I am trying to start the domain in Glassfish 4.1 and I am getting the following error message

```
Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:
Error: Could not find or load main class .M;C:.Program

Command start-domain failed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I actually created a brand new installation of glassfish. All I did was run create-domain. It created fine, but this happened when I tried to start it.

Comment: You running this on Windows?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Look at this link...Could be your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994498/cannot-start-glassfish-in-eclipse-glassfish-error-could-not-find-or-load-main